# In Texstudio "Go to error when displaying log" does not work

Tags: compiling

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351968/disable-cursor-to-jump-to-error-location-after-compile-in-texstudio), I did this:

[Options] --> [Adv. Editor] --> [Special options] panel --> [Go to error when displaying log]

which however doesn't resolve my issue; after compiling, the cursor is always stuck at the same place. I'm suspecting some part of my code is colliding with this functionality, but cannot figure which.

Edit: I tried unmarking the checkbox for "Go to error when displaying log" and it is now working! I thought it should be marked, but it seems not.

Comment: You could test if this is caused by something in your code by trying a simple test document. Does it work there?

Comment: @samcarter, yes it works in a test document. Now, my tex code is very long and so may I ask how I can identify which code collides with the functionality?

Comment: Jumping to the error works normally really good, unless the error is so catastrophic that latex can't recover from the error to finish syntax checking the rest of the document. You could try to narrow down the problem by making a copy of your project and then keep removing stuff so long as you can still reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried unmarking the checkbox for "Go to error when displaying log" and it is now working! I thought it should be marked, but it seems not.